# Gnuplot's Graphic Jump

Tags: gnuplot

is there a way to avoid the drawing of the near asymptote line in the function `1/(2-x)`, for example, **without** usage of conditional plotting? The idea is to draw iterated functions based in this one and, since asymptote changes, using conditional plotting isn't a good solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can plot `with points` at a very high sampling rate:

   ```
   set yrange [-10:10]
   set samples 100000
   plot 1/(2-x) with points
   ```

[image]

2. If the singularity occurs at different values of `x` you can use conditional plotting on `y`:

   ```
   f(x)=1/(2-x)
   set samples 1000
   plot (abs(f(x)) < 10 ? f(x) : 1/0) with lines
   ```

[image]